# QField - Issue in a Project with pre-existent pictures

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I'm trying to make a project in an instance of Private Cloud, where I want to insert attachments in a project that already has images collected in the field.

That is, uploading a pre-existing project with several attachments, and continuing to upload attachments from there.

However, when I do the composition relationship process, and the form configuration, everything works normally in QGIS, I can use it normally as it should, but in QField, the images are copied to the device, but are not loaded to the form.

Tested in the latest versions of QField and in the LTR version of QGIS.

Does anyone know how to proceed?